# How to access a value within JSON body response (using Request module to make GET requests to an external API)

Tags: node.js, json, express, request, body-parser

I am using Express and Node.js to create a simple API that pulls data from an external source.   Upon running the code in the block below and  entering my /api/posts/tech endpoint into Insomnia I receive a response body with a JSON object that looks like:

```
    {
    "posts": [
        {
            "author": "Rylee Paul",
            "authorId": 9,
            "id": 1,
            "likes": 960,
            "popularity": 0.13,
            "reads": 50361,
            "tags": [
                "tech",
                "health"
            ]
        },
        {
            "author": "Zackery Turner",
            "authorId": 12,
            "id": 2,
            "likes": 469,
            "popularity": 0.68,
            "reads": 90406,
            "tags": [
                "startups",
                "tech",
                "history"
            ]
        },
        {
            "author": "Elisha Friedman",
            "authorId": 8,
            "id": 4,
            "likes": 728,
            "popularity": 0.88,
            "reads": 19645,
            "tags": [
                "science",
                "design",
                "tech"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to GET just the value of "posts" within the body response so I can manipulate the order of the objects within that array.

I am using the "request" node module to complete my GET request.

Here is the code in my index.js file for this basic Express API:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
const { response } = require('express');

// set up express server connection to the local port
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001

// using body parser to parse the json data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api/posts/:tag', (req, res) => {
    const { tag } = req.params;
    request(`https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/blog/posts?tag=${tag}`, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // returns raw response data
            res.send(body);
        } else
            console.log(error);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is live on port: ${port}`);
});
```

In other projects I have been able to just affix the key value with a period like this: `res.send(body.posts)` rather than returning `res.send(body)`.  But that sends an error message "No body returned for response".

Perhaps it has something to do with the body-parser or request modules that I just haven't figured out.   Any help or insight will be appreciated.   Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by parsing it as JSON, as that's what the API is returning.
JSON is a simple structure for data that the computer interprets.

Here is a working version of your code:

```js
request(`https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/blog/posts?tag=${tag}`, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // returns raw response data
            let struct = JSON.parse(body);
            res.send(struct.posts);
        } else
            console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: thank you!! your solution worked just as I needed it to.

Comment: If it helped! Mark my question as the accepted answer so other people can see it easier if they run into the same issue.